# Proving limits existance

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Im supposed to show and justify if the limit exists of this fucntion.
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos x-1-x^2/2}{x^4+y^4}$$
One way the solution says is fine is to approach along the line $y=0$ which im fine with. so then
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1-x^2/2}{x^4}$$
But then it says that using l'hopitals rule this is evaluated to $-\infty$ which I do not understand. Im wondering if anyone can explain why this becomes $-\infty$ Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ For your second limit, think about Maclaurin series.

Comment: They already did to get $(1-x^2/2 + \cdots)-1-x^2/2 = -x^2 + \cdots$. Sign trickery to make sure read the question.

Comment: @AHusain how does that show that it becomes infinity. Im missing something doesnt that just cancel the first two terms and then you have a polynomial over x^4. Why does using l'hopitals rule show that becomes infinity. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The first two terms don't cancel. You are left with $\frac{-x^2+\cdots}{x^4}$. The $\cdots$ start with something proportional to $x^4$ so the main thing to worry about is the $\frac{-x^2}{x^4} = \frac{-1}{x^2}$ which is blowing up to $-\infty$.

Alternatively without series:

$$
\frac{\cos x - 1 - x^2/2}{x^4} \to \frac{- \sin x - x}{4x^3}\\
\to \frac{-\cos x - 1}{12x^2}
$$

with 2 applications of l'Hopital and then you can show that last quantity is blowing up like $\frac{-2}{12x^2} \to -\infty$.

Comment: how are you aloud to input the zero into the top but not the bottom? Is it because  the top will always be in a small range anyways?

Comment: Exactly. You have to do that part still. Give an upper bound for the quantity that works for all $x<\delta$.